# Windows server 2012, missing WMI ASPNET counters

Tags: asp.net, windows-server-2012, wmi

I've been using the following WMI query to check how many IIS sites are currently running on my Windows 2008 webservers:

```
SELECT ApplicationsRunning FROM Win32_PerfRawData_ASPNET4030319_ASPNETv4030319
```

After replacing these webservers with 2012 equivalents, this query always returns 0, even though my sites run ASP.Net 4.

Does anyone know why this happens, and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

I found this KB article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2869514

> After installing .NET 4.5 you are not able to access performance data
>   using WMI. For example, when you try to get the value for the
>   Win32_PerfFormattedData_ASPNET_ASPNETApplications performance counter,
>   the value returned using WMI is always 0.
>
> This is by design as a security fix. Only admin and performance log/monitor can access asp.net performance information.

Unfortunately I haven't yet found a way to make it work.

Comment: Sorry about the late reply, this does sound like the cause - I'll try using an admin account and see if that solves it :-)